# git how branching works inside

Tags: git, branch, dvcs

I'm using github and interesting, how git branching works inside. Is it copy some data when creating new branch or not. How and where it store the difference of the branches and how it allow to switching between them fast. What's happened with my files on disk when I'm changing the brunch?

Answer (score 2):

A branch is a label on a commit that moves the a new commit when added while that label is the active 'branch' of the tree of commits.  Multiple branches result when additional labels are created, made active and commits added to that 'branch'.

Internally, the storage of a branch is just that, a label that points to the commit it is attached to.

A good beginning reference is this chapter in the git book: [3.2 Git Branching - Basic Branching and Merging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging).

Answer (score 0):

github is a web site. I think you mean git, which is the software. And if you want a basic understanding of its design, I suggest you look at the wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)

Answer (score 0):

The Git branching chapter in Pro Git is a good start: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching